# Как привязать два разных свойства к CheckBox.IsChecked?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Не могу сообразить, как привязать два разных свойства к CheckBox на форме WPF
Есть свойство IsCheckedManualQ, и есть свойство VNATrigger

```
<CheckBox   x:Name="CheckManualQ" Content="Ввести вручную  Q&#8320;n /  Q&#8321;n"  
            FontWeight="Medium" 
            FontSize="12" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0"
            IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedManualQ}">
                    <CheckBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=VNATrigger}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="CheckBox.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=VNATrigger}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="CheckBox.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </CheckBox.Style>
                </CheckBox>
```

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на CheckBox - свойство bool IsCheckedManualQ изменялось. А когда нажимает другую кнопку, которая задает значение bool VNATrigger - то это воздействовало на CheckBox (переводило в IsChecked в True)и блокировало его если VNATrigger True и разблокировала если False (и у CheckBox.IsChecked становилось  = True).

Если убрать в CheckBox'e вверху

```
   ..............
     DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0"
     IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedManualQ}"> - -- вот это
```

Тогда все работает как надо, но соответственно пропадает привязка к свойству IsCheckedManualQ - а мне нужно и то и другое
Есть какие нибудь простые методы этого достигнуть?

Свойство VNATrigger

```
  #region VNATirgger 
        private bool _VNATrigger = false;
        public bool VNATrigger
        {
            get => _VNATrigger;
            set => Set(ref _VNATrigger, value);
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: Покажите код обоих свойств

Comment: Также вы никак не отреагировали га ответ, который я вам дал в прошлом вопросе

Comment: @aepot да меня тут отвлекли на другие дела, сейчас как раз пытаюсь воспроизвести у себя все по вашему ответу там, обязательно отпишусь о результате) - Добавил свойство VNATrigger, оно черезе INPC, свойство IsCheckedManualQ - абсолютно точно такое же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разделите задачу на 2 части: управление доступностью и управление состоянием чекбокса

Управление доступностью сделать просто, просто убрать лишнее:

```xml
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckManualQ" Content="Ввести вручную  Q&#8320;n /  Q&#8321;n"  
          FontWeight="Medium" 
          FontSize="12" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0"
          IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedManualQ}">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding VNATrigger}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Управление состоянием, это переключить в `true` свойство `IsCheckedManualQ` если `VNATrigger` получил состояние `true`. Это уже можно сделать в коде вьюмодели.

```cs
private bool _VNATrigger;

public bool VNATrigger
{
    get => _VNATrigger;
    set
    {
        if (value)
            IsCheckedManualQ = value;
        Set(ref _VNATrigger, value);
    }
}
```

Вот и всего делов. Главное - не перемешивать задачи, и всё встанет на свои места.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался) Все получилось, как хотел)